# Case Condition in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, case

I am trying to implement a case condition in python pandas.

The Sql equivalent is as below -

```
case when entered_by = created_by_user then entered_by
            when entered_by = entered_by then entered_by
            when modified_by = created_by_user then modified_by
            when modified_by = entered_by then modified_by
      end as "AD_ID"
```

I have written the below pandas code to achieve the above, but getting an error-

```
def func(row):
    if dftemp['entered_by'] == dftemp['created_by_user']:
        return dftemp['entered_by']
    elif dftemp['entered_by'] == dftemp['entered_by']:
        return dftemp['entered_by']
    elif dftemp['modified_by'] == dftemp['created_by_user']:
        return dftemp['modified_by']
    elif dftemp['modified_by'] == dftemp['entered_by']:
        return dftemp['modified_by']    
    else:
        return 'other'

dftemp['AD_ID'] = dftemp.apply(func, axis=1)
```

I am getting the below error -

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')
```

Is there a better way of achieving the same?

Thanks.

@Donkey Kong - I tried the below, didnt work -

```
def func(row):
    if assert_series_equal(dftemp['entered_by'], dftemp['created_by_user']):
        return dftemp['entered_by']
    elif assert_series_equal(dftemp['entered_by'], dftemp['entered_by']):
        return dftemp['entered_by']
    elif assert_series_equal(dftemp['modified_by'], dftemp['created_by_user']):
        return dftemp['modified_by']
    elif assert_series_equal(dftemp['modified_by'], dftemp['entered_by']):
        return dftemp['modified_by']    
    else:
        return 'other'

dftemp['AD_ID'] = dftemp.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your func takes row as a parameter, but it is not used.  All of the dftemp variables should be row.  Also, I believe this is cleaner:

```
def func(row):
    if assert_series_equal(row.entered_by in [row.created_by_user, row.entered_by]):
        return dftemp.entered_by
    if assert_series_equal(row.modified_by in [row.created_by_user, row.entered_by]):
        return dftemp.modified_by 
    return 'other'
```